# Problem with Hibernate.initialize(...) I got LazyInitializationException but when I debug everything is fine

Tags: java, hibernate, debugging, lazy-initialization

I am loading 2.5 million complex object to MS SQL.
Because of performance I am using kind of cache in memory.
During this process I call `Hibernate.initialize(...)` 
Using default JVM settings application fail always in the same place (every time the same record failed).

I have three `Set<>` and I call three times `Hibernate.initialize(...)`
(**section A** ) 
Always second `Set<>` is not properly initialized.

- When I set breakpoint before initialization and go through code then
  everything is fine (no problem occured / no exception happen)
- When I set breakpoint after `LazyInitializationException` occurred
  then issue always happen.
- When I test `id` of record and call `toString()` after initialization
  then everything is fine (no problem occured / no exception happen) - **section B**

code looks like:

```
 private SomeObject getObject(int id) {
     SomeObject result = null;
     if(!cache.containsKey(id)) {
         SomeObject obj = context.getEntity(SomeObject.class, new ContextKey(id));

         // section A
         Hibernate.initialize(((SomeParentObject)obj.getField()).getSetA());
         Hibernate.initialize(((SomeParentObject)obj.getField()).getSetB());
         Hibernate.initialize(((SomeParentObject)obj.getField()).getSetC());

         // section B
         if(id == 1234) {
             ((SomeParentObject)obj.getField()).getSetB().toString();
         }

         cache.put(id, obj);
         result = obj;
     } else {
         result = cache.get(id);
     }
     return result;
 }
```

`LazyInitializationException` occurred after usage this method.

1. Any idea why it can be like this?
2. How to debug this kind of
   problems?

Answer (score 1):

You might have Set<> with fetch type as Lazy and when you are calling it, they might not be in same transaction.

Hence, causing the issue but it will fork fine when you debug.
Try setting fetch type as EAGER.

Answer (score 0):

I found **workaround** (to avoid changing hibernate configuration etc.) - when I use:

> ```
>     ((SomeParentObject)obj.getField()).getSetA().size();
>     ((SomeParentObject)obj.getField()).getSetB().size();
>     ((SomeParentObject)obj.getField()).getSetC().size();
> ```

instead of `Hibernate.initialize(...)` then it is working fine.